# AWS Image for Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, amazon-ami, vnc

I'm trying to practice this Kubernetes book and am encountering the following obstacles:

1. I have Windows 10 Home and cannot install Docker Desktop.

So I want to use AWS EC2.

2. Windows Server RDP gave me trouble and I could not figure out how to install packages from the CLI. I also had permission headaches with the web browser.

So I chose Amazon Linux 2 AMI. Docker, Kubernetes, Git, all install correctly.

3. But I need to install a GUI and web browser for certain exercises in the course, which I get stuck on.

Am I missing some easy solution? Aside from buying a new version of Windows?

Comment: you could use amazon ecs - elastic container service.

Comment: try the minikube from [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/). I think this is the easiest way to see thing with kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you to install and run your Minikube installation inside your AWS.

It's recommended to follow this steps to install your instance, don't look for a pre-installed image.

I'm considering you already have an Ubuntu/Debian instance with at least 4GB RAM and 2vCPU. (If you plan on running Prometheus or other resource-hungry component I recomend 8GB RAM at least)

SSH into your instance and follow this 5 steps:

**1. Install kubectl:**

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl`
chmod +x ./kubectl
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

**2. Install Docker:**

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker.io -y`

**3. Install Minikube**:

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

**4. Check Minikube Version:**

`minikube version`

**5. Start Minikube:**

`minikube start --vm-driver=none`

And check status with `minikube status`.

If you screw up your minikube, just type `minikube delete` and the whole cluster will be trashed, thus you can `minikube start --vm-driver=none` and start over again.

Keep in mind that Minikube is purposed for learning, developing and testing purposes.

More info at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/search/?q=minikube